# Please guide on c# equivalent stuff of VB.NET (new to vb.net)

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, oop, events

Can any one share with me an equivalent of the below code in vb.net.

```
public class Class1 : ComboBox
{
    public event ItemCheckEventHandler ItemCheck;

    public class f
    {
        private Class1 c;

        public f(Class1 c1)
        {
            c = c1;
            c.ItemCheck += c_ItemCheck;
        }

        void c_ItemCheck(object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs e)
        {
            c.ItemCheck(sender, e);
        }
    }
}
```

Bellow is an equivalent (converted code):

```
Public Class Class1
    Inherits ComboBox

    Public Event ItemCheck As ItemCheckEventHandler
        Public Class f
        Private c As Class1

        Public Sub New(c1 As Class1)
            c = c1
            AddHandler c.ItemCheck, AddressOf c_ItemCheck
        End Sub

        Private Sub c_ItemCheck(sender As Object, e As ItemCheckEventArgs)
            RaiseEvent c.ItemCheck(sender, e)  
        End Sub
    End Class
End Class
```

Problem: c# is working fine, but in the converted code the `RaiseEvent` statement gives the following errors:

1. c is not an event of app.f
2. End of statement expected

can any one share with me a correct syntax.

Thanks

Comment: How did you define a class INSIDE a class ?

Comment: Its just same as above example stuff. class inside a class that is same working in c#. but vb.net giving an error when raiseevent then unable to find event through object.

Comment: you cannot raise the event of outer class from the inner class

Comment: BUt, raising through instance.

Comment: @paritosh: The C# code is valid - it's strange that VB doesn't allow this.

Comment: @CarstenKönig: There are 2 ways to declare events in VB: 1. As an existing delegate type (as in this post) or 2. With a signature or implicit delegate (this is what you are suggesting).

Comment: yeah - just saw your accepted answer ;) - sorry (I really don't write that much VB anymore)

Comment: It has been too long since I've done this, but I *believe* the trick lies in adding `WithEvents` to the nested class variable. You'll have to play around with it, though; I don't have a VB.NET compiler handy for testing purposes

Comment: @user3711357: Don't worry about it - some people here are just automatically very prickly about source code conversion questions. I think your question is a very good question. Who would have thought that C# allows raising outer class events from an inner class, while VB doesn't?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's strange that VB doesn't allow this directly, but you can do it by adding a method to your outer class to raise the event:

```
Public Class Class1
    Inherits ComboBox

    Public Event ItemCheck As ItemCheckEventHandler

    Public Sub RaiseItemCheckEvent(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As ItemCheckEventArgs)
        RaiseEvent ItemCheck(sender, e)
    End Sub

    Public Class f
        Private c As Class1

        Public Sub New(ByVal c1 As Class1)
            c = c1
            AddHandler c.ItemCheck, AddressOf c_ItemCheck
        End Sub

        Private Sub c_ItemCheck(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As ItemCheckEventArgs)
            c.RaiseItemCheckEvent(sender, e)
        End Sub

    End Class

End Class
```

Comment: hmm. Thank you for this alternative way. it works able to achieve required thing.

Comment: This is why the framework guidelines recommend an `OnEvent` function to raise the event.

Answer (score -1):

you need to declare the event inside the class

```
Public Class f
    Public Event ItemCheck As EventHandler

    Private c As Class1

    Public Sub New(c1 As Class1)
        c = c1
        AddHandler c.ItemCheck, AddressOf c_ItemCheck
    End Sub

    Private Sub c_ItemCheck(sender As Object, e As ItemCheckEventArgs)
        RaiseEvent ItemCheck(sender, e)
    End Sub



End Class
```

Comment: getting same error . I need the event in parent class and access in child class. same as C# stuff.